# How to catch touches within some figure/shape on Android screen?

Tags: android, shapes

If one has Android screen with some figure/shape, like on example below,
how to get info when touched within a figure (e.g. within red or blue figure)?
How to define those figures and what API to use?
Note, hope to find simplest solution without deep dive into graphics, as for the app it is just selection screen.
(Figures maybe of any form so breaking screen into logical squares will not work. It should within figures, however they are.)

[image: scr2]